# Jquery delegate Scroll event on position fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="scroll-box">
    <div id="header" style="position:fixed">...</div>
    <div id="main">...</div>
</div>
```

I tried to delegate the scroll event of the scroll-box event if the user scrolls with the mouse over the header:

```
$('#scroll-box').delegate('#header', 'scroll', function(){
    alert("scroll");
    });
```

This is not working. 
How can I trigger the scroll event of the scroll-box even if the mouse is over the header and the user scrolls?

Comment: Well this question is answered here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505182/bind-scroll-event-to-dynamic-div/31498537#31498537

Answer (score 2):

You can't delegate the scroll event because the scroll event doesn't bubble.  Delegation works only for events that bubble.