# How to capture scroll event on Select2 dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How to capture the `scroll` event for HTML element that using `Select2`? 
I want to capture the scroll event for dynamically adding `<option>` into my dropdown.

**For your infomation:**

- I'm using `jQuery`, and the dropdown using `Select2`.
- The `id` that of my HTML element is `d`. (Although the naming isn't appropriate, will rename it later)

**Testing solution 1: (Not working)**

```
$("body").on("scroll", "#select2-d-results", function(){
   alert('scroll');
})
```

**Testing solution 2: (Not working)**

```
$('#select2-d-results').scroll(function() {
   alert('scroll');
});
```

[image: My Dropdown Selections]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the scroll event does not bubble up in DOM

**Method 1**

Using `mousewheel` event instead of scroll

**Method 2** (recommended)

Using `addEventListener`

[Jquery .on('scroll') not firing the event while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375636/jquery-onscroll-not-firing-the-event-while-scrolling)

```js
$("#d").select2();

// using on mousedown 
$("body").on("mousewheel", "#select2-d-results", function(){
   console.log('mousewheel');
})

// using addEventListener
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (event.target.id === 'select2-d-results') { 
        console.log('scrolling');
    }
}, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="d" style="width: 300px">
  <option value="1">Argentina</option>
  <option value="2">Brazil</option>
  <option value="3">China</option>
  <option value="4">India</option>
  <option value="5">Indonesia</option>
  <option value="1">Argentina</option>
  <option value="2">Brazil</option>
  <option value="3">China</option>
  <option value="4">India</option>
  <option value="5">Indonesia</option>
</select>
```