# Binding jquery event scroll with "on"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a problem, why this work

```
$(selector).scroll(function(e) {
    console.log("Scrolling");
});
```

and this not

```
$(document).on("scroll", selector, function(e) {
    console.log("Scrolling");
});
```

This is selector

```
var selector = "#schedule td > div.k-scheduler-content, #schedule td > div.k-scheduler-header";
```

The scroll event by "on" not work... I don't know why...
Check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/CjfoIPTCqScS1znAwmIs?p=preview

**UPDATE**

Maybe I found a solution that work:

```
document.addEventListener(
  'scroll',
  function(event){
    var $elm = $(event.target);
    if( $elm.is(selector) ) { // or any other filtering condition
      // do some stuff
      console.log('scrolling');
    } else {
      console.log("selector different");
    }
  },
  true // Capture event
);
```

Comment: I don't think you need the selector twice, remove it from the parameters in your `on` call

Comment: Check plunker, it not work

Comment: in your Plunker link, I noticed that you are calling the js code BEFORE the DOM, so that is why it doesn't work, either use the ready method or move the script into the DOM and it worked for me

Comment: move `<script src="script.js"></script>` to just above closing `</body>'

Comment: @Nate No; that's not the reason it's not working. The `scroll` event doesn't bubble, which means that it can't be delegated.

Comment: you might be right, but it worked for me in the Plunker example.
https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: I need to bind event to document, because div is dynamic...

Comment: I did have to rewrite the jquery selector, so if it can't be delegated then you can't do it for dynamic divs....  `$("#test").on("scroll", function() {console.log("Scrolling");});`

Comment: It's a big problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it like following :

```
$("#test").on("scroll", function() {
    console.log("Scrolling");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check plunker, not work params you provided also...

Comment: @Davide check my update please.

Comment: Not work with dynamic div D:

Comment: Why?!! i think `.on` should deal with fresh DOM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28777181/4637430

Comment: You can see that it work in this **[basic example](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/6/)**.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/35/ Check